# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir Kubernetes Pod

Tags: node.js, typescript, enoent

I'm trying to upload files with `multer` from my typescript/express app. I have tested the application locally on mac it's working fine with a folder `uploads` under `src`. It worked well for the Local docker container too without any issue. But, once I deploy it to Kubernetes the paths are not working. The plan is if the `uploads` folder does not exist then the app will create the folder using -

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req: Request, file: Express.Multer.File, callback: any) {
    // const _baseUploadPath: string = path.join('./src', '..', 'abc_uploads');
    const _baseUploadPath: string = path.join('../', 'uploads');

    const _folderIdentifier: string | undefined = RequestTracker.requestId;
    const _tmpPath: string = path.resolve(_baseUploadPath, `_tmp_${_folderIdentifier}`);

    fs.existsSync(_baseUploadPath) || fs.mkdirSync(_baseUploadPath);
    fs.existsSync(_tmpPath) || fs.mkdirSync(_tmpPath);

    callback(null, _tmpPath);
  },

  filename: function(req: Request, file: Express.Multer.File, callback: any) {
    callback(null, file.originalname.substring(0, file.originalname.indexOf(".")) + path.extname(file.originalname));
    return;
  }
});
```

Now, I am getting the error -  `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir`.

Even if the folder is present and I'm login to the pod terminal and change the permission of the folder as 777 still the sub folders not getting created .

Can anyone please help.